# Как можно сделать адаптер для трансляции запросов с websocket на tcp-сервер?

Tags: nginx, websocket, клиент-сервер

Есть tcp-клиент и tcp-сервер, которые успешно работают.
Возникла необходимость сделать поддержку клиентов с браузера через websocket.

Как можно сделать адаптер для трансляции запросов с websocket на tcp-сервер?
Допускается использование nginx.

Comment: Может всеже пару строк на питоне? А то ws это пакетная передача, а tcp потоковая. Как nginx узнает как резать ваши сообщения?

Comment: @eri, о какой паре строк вы говорите?

Comment: Вэб сервер написать, который будет устанавливать соединение с вашим сервером

Comment: https://github.com/vi/websocat вот например

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51164513 тут немного наоборот вопрос задан

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с использованием `websockify`